# VS Code console.log does not output to console

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, console.log

After the last VS Code update 1.49.2, console.log (javascript) does not produce any output to debugger console.
Node.js version is 12.14.1

I reinstalled both VS Code and node.js.

I don't know what else to try, and google is not working.

What do you need to help me track and solve this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: If you view the console in the developer tools of Chrome, does it show the console.log message?

Comment: what package do you use for starter?

Comment: DJ Burb, it does show in Chrome console, and it did use to show in VS Code.
Gilang, I don't know what package I am using for started, what does that mean and how can I check please?